# Loop through function in python generating separate list for each set of data

Tags: python, list, loops

So I have the following:

```
import PROGRAMS as prg

testlist = []
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
functions = [prg.test1, prg.test2, prg.test3]

for func in functions:
    for j in y:
        x = j*2
        z = func(x)
        testlist.append(z)

print testlist

#####PROGRAMS
def test1(x):
    x=x**2

    return x

def test2(x):
    x=x**3

    return x

def test3(x):
    x=x+10

    return x
```

Say now I want to generate a separate testlist for each function. I.e have a list containing all data from running the loop with test1, then a separate list for data from test2 etc...

Ideally I wouldn't like to define 3 separate lists testlist1, testlist2 etc. but rather have a system where a list is generated based on the length of the list 'functions' and somehow implement into what I already have.

Thank you in advance, 
Sven.

Comment: Sorry English is not my first language by that i mean len(functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a separate list of value per function:

```
outlists = []

for func in functions:
    thislist = []
    for j in y:
        thislist.append(func(j*2))
    outlists.append(thislist)
```

`outlists` will contain one list per function.

You could also do this with nested list comprehensions:

```
outlists = [[func(j*2) for j in y] for func in functions]
```

but this goes past some people's comfort level.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect - sorry for my bad english!